# Extract key value pair data from json object, Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

i need to extract key value pair data from this json array. I need to extract data like the 'producId' as well as availability status inside array with in a parent array.

```
data=[
 {
  "productId": 1001080012,
  "storeNumber": 289,
  "isSosVendorDirect": true,
  "price": {
   "selling": "249.00",
   "retail": "249.00",
   "typeCode": 1,
   "typeIndicator": "Regular Price"
  },
  "availability": 
  [
   {
    "availabilityStatus": "Available",
    "productStockType": "STK",
    "availabileQuantity": 822,
    "deliveryMethodId": 1,
    "deliveryMethodName": "Parcel Shipping",
    "storeNumber": 907
   },
   {
    "availabilityStatus": "Available",
    "productStockType": "STK",
    "availabileQuantity": 1,
    "leadTime": 1570607222335,
    "deliveryMethodId": 2,
    "deliveryMethodName": "Store Pickup",
    "storeNumber": 289
   },
   {
    "availabilityStatus": "Available",
    "productStockType": "STK",
    "availabileQuantity": 1,
    "leadTime": 1570607222335,
    "deliveryMethodId": 3,
    "deliveryMethodName": "Truck Delivery",
    "storeNumber": 289
   }
  ],
  "@type": "item"
 }
]
```

I have tired using.

```
price=data[selling]
store=data[storeNumber]
```

Comment: did you try the json module function json.loads?

Comment: You cannot use a json directly. First you need to load it. The json data need to a string, or a plain text file to be loaded. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is a length 1 array, you have to call the 0th index first.

```
price=data[0]['price']['selling']
store=data[0]['storeNumber']

print(price, store)
```

The result is as follows:

```
249.00 289
```

You can also have the `storeNumber`s in the availability key which has different values. In this case, you have to specify which value you want to pick but I don't know what you want.

Comment: its throwing out the error, "true is not defined "'isSosVendorDirect': true"

Comment: That is right. I was modified into `True` but you can load your data as a string and parse as json, e.g. @alec_djinn's example.

Comment: How can we achieve if it is a multi dimensional array?

Answer (score 2):

You have a mix of nested lists and dictionaries. Looking at it you can figure out the structure.

Assuming your data to be:

```
txt = '''
[
 {
  "productId": 1001080012,
  "storeNumber": 289,
  "isSosVendorDirect": true,
  "price": {
   "selling": "249.00",
   "retail": "249.00",
   "typeCode": 1,
   "typeIndicator": "Regular Price"
  },
  "availability": 
  [
   {
    "availabilityStatus": "Available",
    "productStockType": "STK",
    "availabileQuantity": 822,
    "deliveryMethodId": 1,
    "deliveryMethodName": "Parcel Shipping",
    "storeNumber": 907
   },
   {
    "availabilityStatus": "Available",
    "productStockType": "STK",
    "availabileQuantity": 1,
    "leadTime": 1570607222335,
    "deliveryMethodId": 2,
    "deliveryMethodName": "Store Pickup",
    "storeNumber": 289
   },
   {
    "availabilityStatus": "Available",
    "productStockType": "STK",
    "availabileQuantity": 1,
    "leadTime": 1570607222335,
    "deliveryMethodId": 3,
    "deliveryMethodName": "Truck Delivery",
    "storeNumber": 289
   }
  ],
  "@type": "item"
 }
]
'''
```

Then:

```
import json
data = json.loads(txt)

price = data[0]['price']['selling']
print(price)

store = data[0]['availability'][0]['storeNumber']
print(store)
```

Output:

```
249.00
907
```